# speech recognition for anaconda installation

Tags: anaconda, python-3.7

I am currently trying to install speech recognition for anaconda but I am getting error

(base) C:>conda install -c conda - forge/label/cf201901
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - -
  - forge/label/cf201901

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: it looks like a typo: `-c conda - forge/label/cf201901` should be `-c conda-forge/label/cf201901`, i.e., no spaces. However, that's just a channel, not a package. What was the package? More importantly, do you really need that specific labeled channel? That is specifically for builds of packages using a pre-2019 compiler set. You probably just want `conda install -c conda-forge my_pkg`

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge speechrecognition
```

The output will be:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
conda-4.10.3         | 3.1 MB    | ############################################################################################ | 100% 
speechrecognition-3. | 31.8 MB   | ############################################################################################ | 100% 
python_abi-3.8       | 4 KB      | ############################################################################################ | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

try to install using Anaconda Navigator: go to Anaconda Navigator, Environments, (select your environment), click on the dropdown with 'Installed', and change to 'Uninstalled', search the package you need, check the box beside the name of the package and finally click on 'Apply'.

Answer (score 0):

Your command makes no sense. `forge/label/cf201901` is a channel name.

If you wanna install a pkg from specific channel, like `forge/label/cf201901`. Try following command

```sh
conda install --channel "conda-forge/label/cf201901" package
```