# Unable to install mesa using anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda, mesa

I have tried installing mesa using `conda install -c anaconda mesa` as available on their official site [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mesa)

But I am getting the following error message

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - mesa
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: The problem is that there's no mesa for windows in the conda channels.

Answer (score 0):

try to install using Anaconda Navigator: go to Anaconda Navigator, Environments, (select your environment), click on the dropdown with 'Installed', and change to 'Uninstalled', search the package you need, check the box beside the name of the package and finally click on 'Apply'.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003701/11759947

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the channel to conda forge. It should allow you to install.

```
conda install mesa -c conda-forge
```

You check conda-forge site for more details for installation [Mesa-anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mesa/)