# What went wrong with my installing Geopandas?

Tags: python, git, installation, pip, geopandas

I have followed the [official instruction](https://geopandas.org/install.html) and tried both `pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git` and `pip install geopandas`, but all I got was the below. Not a computer wiz, I simply can't read this. Can somebody help me figure out what I should do to successfully install `geopandas`?

```
PS D:\Python\Scripts> pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
  Cloning git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git to c:\users\ariel\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-mzuz5obu
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.0 in d:\python\lib\site-packages (from geopandas==0.8.0+52.g7e595d0) (1.0.3)
Collecting shapely>=1.6
  Using cached Shapely-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting fiona>=1.8
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.17.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ariel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x28x2nrd\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ariel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x28x2nrd\\fiona\\
setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-kqm2six3'
         cwd: C:\Users\ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x28x2nrd\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
PS D:\Python\Scripts>
```

---

I also tried `pip install -U setuptools` first, and the output is not quite different:

```
PS D:\Python\Scripts> pip install -U setuptools                                                                         Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 785 kB 1.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 41.2.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-41.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-41.2.0
Successfully installed setuptools-50.3.0
PS D:\Python\Scripts> pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
  Cloning git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git to c:\users\ariel\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ujqm8v_3
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.0 in d:\python\lib\site-packages (from geopandas==0.8.0+52.g7e595d0) (1.0.3)
Collecting shapely>=1.6
  Using cached Shapely-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting fiona>=1.8
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.17.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ariel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-no2ywi23\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ariel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-no2ywi23\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8o705rvl'
         cwd: C:\Users\ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-no2ywi23\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
PS D:\Python\Scripts>
```

---

And I installed `Miniconda` and tried what the instruction says:

```
PS D:\Python\Scripts> conda install geopandas
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda install geopandas
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a hassle to install it with pip, so try the following link.
[Conda install some-package hangs with (Solving environment: failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927004/conda-install-some-package-hangs-with-solving-environment-failed)

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I got it right, but it still didn't work and I just added the error output below my question.

Comment: @PawinData yeah saw it. Try out the following command, and link.

Comment: @PawinData this is a pretty comman issue i see, after digging in for a while this is what i found.(look at the latest answer)                                                                                      P.S. I tested it on my pc and it works.

Comment: Thank you! I just installed Miniconda, but somehow `conda install` doesn't seem to be recognized. I pasted the output again.

Comment: it is because you did not add minicoda to PATH. You could either add it to PATH or use the Anaconda promet to and it will work.