# Solving environment: Failed with initial frozen solve. Jupyter notebook, Anacoda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am follow the instruction from this website,
https://fenicsproject.org/download/

```
!conda config --add channels conda-forge
!conda install fenics
```

But it said:

```
Solving environment: Failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving enviroment: Failed with repodata from current_repodata.jason, will retry with next repodata source.
```

and no more progressing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda returns 'Solving environment: failed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266535/conda-returns-solving-environment-failed)

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem by doing the following:

```
conda update --all --yes
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install fenics
```

Comment: Try also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927004/conda-install-some-package-hangs-with-solving-environment-failed