# Unable to install pycluster on windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

When installing `pycluster` in Jupyter Notebook on windows, using command -

**conda install -c bioconda pycluster**

I am getting following  response -

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - pycluster

I have tried installing using command `conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 pycluster`. But the response is same.

Comment: [try to install using Anaconda Navigator: go to Anaconda Navigator, Environments, (select your environment), click on the dropdown with 'Installed', and change to 'Uninstalled', search the package you need, check the box beside the name of the package and finally click on 'Apply'.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003701/11759947)

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713274/error-failed-building-wheel-for-pycryptodome

Answer (score 0):

Can install with following instruction :

```
pip install pyclustering
```