# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pycryptodome

I was trying to install `pycryptodome`, `python-jose-cryptodome` using `pip` within **anaocnda3** environment.

I got this error:

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome
```

I have tried many versions many solutions(latest versions, specified version, with python 3.8 or 3.7, using requirements text without cache and even alone installation) but nothing worked for me :(. Any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**While** using `pip` in an anaconda environment is allowed and fine, issues may arise when using `pip` and `conda` together, this was clearly mentioned in the conda [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).

One of the best practices when installing packages in an anaconda environment is to use `conda` for search and install before using pip.

**So** instead of directly using `pip`, try to :

1. **Search** for pycryptodome in anaconda packages repo

   `conda search pycryptodome`

   pycryptodome is available in anaconda repo .
2. The next step is to install pycryptodome :

   `conda install -c anaconda pycryptodome`

   or if you want to use conda-foge channel :

   `conda install -c conda-forge pycryptodome`

   this should get pycryptodome installed into your env
3. To use a requirements.txt file with conda :

   `conda install --yes --file requirements.txt`

**Summary : Best Practices Checklist When Using Pip in a Conda Environment**

**Use pip only after conda**

- install as many requirements as possible with conda, then use pip
- pip should be run with –upgrade-strategy only-if-needed (the default)
- Do not use pip with the –user argument, avoid all “users” installs

**Use conda environments for isolation**

- create a conda environment to isolate any changes pip makes
- environments take up little space thanks to hard links
- care should be taken to avoid running pip in the “root” environment

**Recreate the environment if changes are needed**

- once pip has been used conda will be unaware of the changes
- to install additional conda packages it is best to recreate the
  environment

**Store conda and pip requirements in text files**

- package requirements can be passed to conda via the –file argument
- pip accepts a list of Python packages with -r or –requirements
- conda env will export or create environments based on a file with
  conda and pip requirements .

you can read more about this topic here [on anaconda website](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/), and on   [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env)